# RxJava: difference between doOnNext and doOnEach

Tags: java, rx-java

In which cases I should use doOnNext, and in which cases
doOnEach?

```
 .doOnEach(new Action1<Notification<? super MessageProfile>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Notification<? super MessageProfile> notification) {

                }
            })
 .doOnNext(new Action1<MessageProfile>() {
                @Override
                public void call(MessageProfile profile) {
                    messageProfileDao.save(profile);
                }
            })
```

This looks like the both operators have the same effect.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

They are indeed quite close.
One thing that differs (and it's maybe not that clear in the javadoc actually, more visible in sourcecode) is that in doOnEach, you also get `Notification` wrappers for errors and completion event.

You can then check `isOnNext`, `isOnCompleted` or `isOnError` to check the actual kind of event you got a notification for.

So one `Action.call` to rule them all, instead of a fully fledged `Observer`