# RxJava alternative for map() operator to save emitted items

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I use Retrofit to interact with a REST API and RxJava do manipulate the data I receive.

In the code snippet below I make an API call and use the `map` operator to save the data I receive before moving on with other operations against the stream.

```
retrofitApi.registerDevice(mDevice)
           .map(new Func1<Device, Device>() {
               @Override
               public Device call(Device device) {
                  // The only purpose of the map() operator 
                  // is to save the received device.
                  magicBox.saveDeviceId(device.getId());
                  return device;
               }
           })
           .otherOperations()...
```

My question is: is there a better operator for the job? I feel like I misuse the `map` operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following [Egor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30149881/1392423) I did some research and, based on [Dan Lew's blogpost](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/22/grokking-rxjava-part-2/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723341/rxjava-difference-between-doonnext-and-dooneach), the correct answer appears to be
 [`doOnNext`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnNext(rx.functions.Action1)).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [doOnEach()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnEach(rx.functions.Action1)) is what you're looking for, however haven't tried it myself.