# Difference between doOnSuccess and doOnEach, and in which use case i should use each of them

Tags: java, spring, java-8, rx-java, flux

I am reviewing a source code file and found in certain commit that we changed the usage of

```
    .doOnSuccess(response -> logBodyAsJSON(response ));
```

Into

```
    .doOnEach(response -> logBodyAsJSON(response ));
```

I cannot find a clear reason to do that.

So what is the difference between doOnSuccess and doOnEach, and in which use case i should use each of them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723341/rxjava-difference-between-doonnext-and-dooneach

Comment: @JulioArboleda, That question discuss something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doOnSuccess` will, as its name implies, only be called when your observable returns an item successfully, and doesn't raise an error. As such, you will only log the confirmation responses.

Also, doOnSuccess works for [Singles](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) or Maybes, which can only emit a single item (you would use doOnNext otherwise). If you use an Observable which can emit multiple items, you'd use `doOnNext` to have the exact same behaviour.

---

`doOnEach` will be called whether the observable emits an item, error or not. It receives a Notification instead of the item itself. It will be called:

- onSuccess and onError for a Single
- onNext, onComplete and onError for a typical Observable

[image]

It's highly likely that the observable item changed from a Single to an Observable. Also, there would exist a need to be able to log errors as well as successes, which is why `doOnNext` wasn't chosen.

Comment: So, doOnEach will be called in case of, onNext, onComplete ,onSuccess and onError ?

Comment: Exact! However, please note that a Single only has onSuccess and onError (no onNext nor onComplete), while a typical Observable has onNext, onComplete and onError (no onSuccess)

Comment: Do you think I should add this info to my answer @MeladBasilius?

Comment: Yes, You can add this info into your answer

Comment: @MeladBasilius Will do! Please remember to accept it if this answers your question, btw.